Applying for a PhD in English with a Low GPA – Any Hope for Acceptance?
Both my graduate and postgraduate degrees have been in English Language and Literature. My MA thesis was on AI and its integration in the humanities. Now, I'm looking to apply to the US, because a) better funding than most countries b) cutting-edge AI research c) best digital humanities schools/faculty apart from the UK/Europe.
My thesis grade was A+, GPA 3.15 in MA and 3.23 in BA. 1 peer-review paper published and another currently under blind-PR at UCBerkeley. For my PhD, I am focusing on AI, computational literary studies and digital humanities.
Would really appreciate some feedback on my chances of getting into a university in the US, given the following places that I'm applying to:
Dream:
Stanford, Cornell, UPenn, Princeton.
Others:
University of Illinois Urbana-Champaign, WashU St. Louis, UC Santa Barbara, UConn, University of Colorado Boulder, University of Arizona, University of Texas at Austin, and Northwestern.
Thanks!

"Better funding" in English PhDs? Citation needed...
